# How to handle Ctrl+n on a list page form?

Tags: axapta, ax

I am trying to handle "ctrl+n" (create new record) action on a list page. I would like to start an wizard after ctrl+n is started. On a normal form I can do it on datasource in create() method. Methods on datasources are disabled on the list page. I can not find a way how to do this. I know it is done somehow on a PurchTableListPage but I can not find how.

How this action can be handled on form with listpage template?

Comment: I know the "ctrl+n" is calling "new" and it invoked same thing as NewPurchOrder menuitem button. But I do not know how is this linked and how it can be setted on my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is on design "newRecordAction" property.